# Chrome PDF Rendering Issue - Anyone ever seen this, or knows how to resolve?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, pdf-generation

A customer of ours using our software has generated a letter.
Our software converts it to a PDF and then displays it to them in a preview window.

This PDF shows correctly on every other computer that we have tested on, but for them, they have an experience of blotchy text.  Some letters are not there, some have been cut in half.
It's worth noting, but when they download the pdf and open it in Chrome in full, it shows without issue.

(I've had to redact personal information, but there should be enough to get a good idea)

Has any one seen this occur.

Chrome 105.0.0.0 - Windows 10

[image: PDF Preview Error]

Comment: Thanks for that information.  I've disabled hardware acceleration on that PC and it's showing correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, turn off accelerated 2D canvas rendering in Google Chrome with the following steps:

1. In Google Chrome, go enter chrome://flags in the address bar and press enter.
2. In the search bar, type accelerated 2d canvas
3. Change the setting from "Enabled" to Disabled
4. Click Relaunch

[Source](https://support.papersapp.com/support/solutions/articles/30000046026-pdf-rendering-issues-in-google-chrome-on-windows-10)